# X-axis of Bar chart doesn't update in Rshiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Here is my sample data, I want to write a shiny app to show a reactive plot on my page but there have something wrong with it.

[image]

And my question is when I select x-axis in bar chart, the plot on shiny won't update but y-axis can update so I don't know where is the problems and how to solve this problem?

[image]

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Data Input# 
Sample <- read.table("D:/Sample.csv", sep = ",", header = T) %>%
  subset(., select = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

#Data Manipulation#
Sample[, c(3:5)] <- sapply(Sample[, c(3:5)], as.factor)
Catego.x <- colnames(Sample[, 3:5])
Catego.y <- colnames(Sample[, 3:5])
Conti <- colnames(Sample[, 1:2])

#ui.R#
shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "Recommendation System",
  navbarMenu(
    "Plot",
    tabPanel("Boxplot", 
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput(inputId = "Conti",
                           label = "Continuous Variables:",
                           choices = Conti),
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.x",
                           label = "Categories Variables:",
                           choices = Catego.x)
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("boxplot")
             )),
    tabPanel("Barchart",
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.x",
                           label = "Categories Variables.x:",
                           choices = Catego.x),
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.y",
                           label = "Categories Variables.y:",
                           choices = Catego.y)
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("barchart")
             ))
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

#Data Input#
Sample <- read.table("D:/Sample.csv", sep = ",", header = T) %>%
  subset(., select = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

#Data Manipulation#
Sample[, c(3:5)] <- sapply(Sample[, c(3:5)], as.factor)
Catego.x <- colnames(Sample[, 3:5])
Catego.y <- colnames(Sample[, 3:5])
Conti <- colnames(Sample[, 1:2])

#server.R#
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Sample, aes_string(x = input$Catego.x, y = input$Conti, group = input$Catego.x)) +
      geom_boxplot()
  })
  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Sample, aes_string(x = input$Catego.x, y = input$Catego.y, fill = input$Catego.y)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you post a dput() of your data? Otherwise we cannot reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that what is causing the problem is an `eventHandler`.

You should add an `actionButton` in your UI and an `eventHandler` in your server part.

UI:

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "Recommendation System",
  navbarMenu(
    "Plot",
    tabPanel("Boxplot", 
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput(inputId = "Conti",
                           label = "Continuous Variables:",
                           choices = Conti),
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.x",
                           label = "Categories Variables:",
                           choices = Catego.x)
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("boxplot")
             )),
    tabPanel("Barchart",
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.x",
                           label = "Categories Variables.x:",
                           choices = Catego.x),
               selectInput(inputId = "Catego.y",
                           label = "Categories Variables.y:",
                           choices = Catego.y),
actionButton(
          inputId = "submit_loc",
          label = "Submit"),
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("barchart")
             ))
  )
))
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$submit_loc,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Sample, aes_string(x = input$Catego.x, y = input$Conti, group = input$Catego.x)) +
      geom_boxplot()
  })
  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = Sample, aes_string(x = input$Catego.x, y = input$Catego.y, fill = input$Catego.y)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
})
})
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: can you do a `dput()` of your data frame?